# Symfony/Doctrine batch processing while working with Gedmo Trees

Tags: php, linux, postgresql, symfony

I'm having memory leakage problems while running a batch script using Symfony2 command and using Doctrine2 following [this guide](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-batch-processing.html). I persist and flush in batches of 50 and call `$em->clear()` after, but when I measure how much memory php uses, every 50-row iteration leaves a `5MB` footprint that does not get freed after the clear call. I've been doing some digging around and it seems to happen after the `$em->flush()` and more specifically when the onFlush events are triggered.

I've removed the entity that was implementing Gedmo Tree and the memory footprint was reduced to `1MB` which is still alot. According to the tutorial it should almost be zero.

I've been scratching my head over this for couple of days and thought I ask the community for some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so you are using the `gc_collect_cycles()` function call? php 5.3+?

Comment: yeap, i do, it only clears around 50K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the script with the `--env=prod` argument and it seems to have resolved my issue.

```
app/console --env=prod my:command:name
```